# Is it correct to use 'my' in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

The following sentence is from 'Rickshaw Kindness' in Reader's digest, August.2018. I am confused with the use of the possessive 'my' in the sentence. Please explain it to me.

> The driver apologised, saying that he had to call on the help of this lady to use my mobile to return the call.

Comment: Can you give more detail about the specific source of your confusion? For instance, do you think the sentence should be saying *her mobile* instead?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a clarifying comment, the question is why *my phone* is being used instead of *his phone*.

A clue to what's going on can be seen when looking at the sentence in the context of the story itself.

A [link](https://www.pressreader.com/australia/readers-digest-asia-pacific/20180801/281672550703050) to Jennifer Cardoza's article "Rickshaw Kindness: Simple generosity can mean the world" shows that the story is written in the first person.

Here are the second and third paragraphs of the story:

> I left my apartment carrying two bags, a handbag and a lunch bag, and boarded an autorickshaw passing nearby. As I walked to the bus stop, I realised I had only my lunch bag – I had left my handbag, containing two ATM cards, a new mobile phone and a sizeable amount of cash, in the autorickshaw!
>
> It took me a few seconds to calm down. Here I was – without so much as a single cent to pay for my bus fare, no mobile to call for help and not a Public Call Office in sight. My work phone number was stored in my mobile so I couldn’t even ring to tell them about my predicament. To add to my woes, I did not have the key to my apartment either. I felt as though I was blindfolded in the middle of a forest.

Accessing the complete story, including the example sentence, requires signing up for an account on the website. But I don't believe I need to do that.

From the context, I either know or am assuming several things:

- *Reader's Digest* normally has autobiographical stories submitted by its readers. So, it's likely that the protagonist in this story is Jennifer Cardoza herself.
- Jennifer forgot her handbag in the back seat of a rickshaw.
- The use of *my mobile* in the example sentence refers to the mobile belonging to Jennifer—which is in her handbag.
- At some point in the story, Jennifer must call the rickshaw driver from some other phone to inquire about her lost handbag.
- Also at some point, somebody calls her—but the call goes to her mobile, still in the rickshaw.
- Another lady must have become a passenger in the rickshaw.
- In order for Jennifer to get back in touch with whoever called her mobile (still in the rickshaw), she tells the driver to instruct the new passenger to return the call.
- In order to return the call, the new passenger must use Jennifer's lost phone.

This is why *my phone* is being used, not *his phone*.